# cygwin - file copy to UNC share

Tags: windows, oracle, cygwin, ksh, unc

First, I know absolutely nothing about CYGWIN so bear with me...

Our developers need to procure some text dumps from our DBAs. They work with Oracle on Windows via a CYGWIN environment, and kornshell.

**Question:** How can we use kornshell/cygwin to copy an old fashioned text file to a standard Windows network share (UNC address)?

---

**Note:** There is a workaround we have discussed, where the DBAs can drop the text files in a local temp folder, and then setup a Windows Task to copy/move the text file to a UNC address. We would like to avoid this kluge.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

UNC paths are mapped to Cygwin paths by replacing `\` characters with `/` characters.

For example, a file that appears in Windows as

```
\\server\dir1\dir2\foo.txt
```

should appear in Cygwin as:

```
//server/dir1/dir2/foo.txt
```

If that doesn't work (it should), you can also map a drive letter to a UNC path.  For example, if you map `\\server\dir1` to `S:\`, then the same file (`S:\dir2\foo.txt`) should appear in Cygwin as `/cygdrive/s/dir2/foo.txt`.

In short, a Cygwin command can treat a directory with a UNC path as an ordinary directory.

See https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#unc-paths

Comment: I realized the problem is not syntax, but rather user/permissions issue... the KSH/Cygwin commands run as a local user account and thus don't have a kerberos ticket with permissions. Our options are, run the script as SYSTEM and trust the computer's AD account on the share... or the ugly workaround i mentioned in my post. thanks for responding though.

Comment: Reference about UNC paths in Cygwin: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#unc-paths

Comment: @kevinarpe Thanks, I've added the link to my answer.